# Backbone fetch to get collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection of records that I am trying to log to the console after a fetch.  I am not sure why the console is logging a lot of methods instead of the data in the records when I log the collection.

How do I log the data in the collection?

The records in the collection contain this:

```
{
  "color": "yellow",
  "date": "March 24, 2014",
  "manufacturer": "Ford",
  "name": "Mustang"
},

{
  "color": "green",
  "date": "July 1, 2014",
  "manufacturer": "Toyota",
  "name": "Corolla"
},

{
  "color": "red",
  "date": "February 2, 2014",
  "manufacturer": "Honda",
  "name": "Civic"
}
```

Here is my Backbone.js code:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'id': 'null',
    'color': '',
    'date': '',
    'name': ''
  }
});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  models: TheModel,

  url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/testdatabase/collections/Content?apiKey=xcdsdfsdczdcdsdfs'
});

var aCollection = new TheCollection();

var TheView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.collection = aCollection.fetch();   
  },

  render: function () {
    console.log('this.collection');
    console.log(this.collection);

    return this;
  }
})

var aView = new TheView();
aView.render();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.collection` will be an instance of a Backbone collection and that's an object with a bunch of methods and data (most of which you won't care about). If you want to look at just the models, then [`this.collection.models`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) is for you:

> **models** `collection.models`
>
> Raw access to the JavaScript array of models inside of the collection.

But that will leave with an array of objects which have a bunch of methods and data that you don't care about.

If you just want the data, then you probably want [`this.collection.toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON):

> **toJSON** `collection.toJSON([options])`
>
> Return an array containing the attributes hash of each model (via `toJSON`) in the collection.

If you've overridden `toJSON` anywhere then you can get around that by extracting the model [`attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes) with something like:

```
console.log(this.collection.map(function(m) { return m.attributes })
```

or, if you don't want to deal with live references in the console:

```
console.log(this.collection.map(function(m) { return _(m.attributes).clone() })
```

That `_(m.attributes).clone()` call is pretty much what the default `toJSON` for models does.

---

Your problems calling methods on `this.collection` stem from this:

```
this.collection = aCollection.fetch();
```

The `fetch` call returns a `jqXHR` (the same thing that [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns), not the collection itself. You want your initialize to look more like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection = aCollection;
}
```

Or you could let Backbone hook up the collection for you. Backbone views will attach some options to the view instances for you, [`collection` is one of these](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) so you could leave out `initialize` and say:

```
var aView = new TheView({ collection: aCollection });
```

Comment: When I try `this.collection.toJSON()` I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".  I am not overriding .toJSON() anywhere.  I'm not sure, but I think it is something with the way I am implementing the .fetch() on the collection because when I log `this.collection.models` it returns "undefined"

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation on what I was doing incorrectly :)